# give multiple params for a tag onclick function in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, regex, spring-boot, jsp

I use a tag onclick function to delete specific documents.
I call the function with three arguments.

but my regex does not include a specific case.

Generally, it works, like "test".
but some case doen't work.

Like this case => "St. John's"

```
 //return '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteName(\'' + key + '\'' + ',\'' + value + '\'' + ',\'' + regionCode + '\');" >[ 삭제 ]</a>' + '</td></tr>';
```

```
 //return '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteName(\'' + key + '\'' + ',\'' + '/\"'+ value + '\'' + '\"/ ' + ',\'' + regionCode + '\');" >[ 삭제 ]</a>' + '</td></tr>';
```

```
const itemsArray = tableData.map(function(item) {
                    var key =  Object.keys(item)[0];
                    var value = Object.values(item);
                    //return '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteName(\'' + key + '\'' + ',\'' + value + '\'' + ',\'' + regionCode + '\');" >[ 삭제 ]</a>' + '</td></tr>';
                    //return '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteName(\'' + key + '\'' + ',\'' + '/\"'+ value + '\'' + '\"/ ' + ',\'' + regionCode + '\');" >[ 삭제 ]</a>' + '</td></tr>';
                    return '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteName(\'' + key + '\''  + ',\'' + "\""  + value  + "\"" + ',\'' + regionCode + '\');" >[ 삭제 ]</a>' + '</td></tr>';
                });
```

this is expected key value example

```
const key = "en";
const value = "test"; // it works
const value = "St. John's"; // it doesn't work.
const regionCode = "AG-ANU";
```

if onclick function call success,

it calls this function

```
function deleteName(key, value, regionCode) {
       $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/regions/" + regionCode + "/names?lang=" + key + "&name=" + value,
            method: "DELETE",
            success: function() {
                alert("삭제되었습니다.");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

I need help for value part regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good way, but I solved like this.

```
  const itemsArray = tableData.map(function(item) {
                    var key =  Object.keys(item)[0];
                    var value = Object.values(item)[0];
                    var valueStr = JSON.stringify(value);
                    var valueString =   value.replace(/'/gi, "\\\'");

                    var keyValueRegionCode = key + "|" + valueString + "|" + regionCode;

                    return '<tr><td>' + key + '</td><td>' + value + '</td><td>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteName(\'' + keyValueRegionCode + '\');">[ 삭제 ]</a>' + '</td></tr>';
                });
```

then calls keyValueRegionCode

```
function deleteName(keyValueRegionCode) {
        var keyValue = keyValueRegionCode.split("|")[0];
        var nameValue = keyValueRegionCode.split("|")[1];
        var regionCode = keyValueRegionCode.split("|")[2];
       $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/regions/" + regionCode + "/names?lang=" + keyValue + "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(nameValue),
            method: "DELETE",
            success: function() {
                alert("삭제되었습니다.");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

1) value.replace(/'/gi, "\\'"); -> this regex makes single apostrophe like this. (\')

2) make parameters one for calling function easily .